# What would happen if T1 is not stricter than T2 in reinterpret-casting?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, reinterpret-cast

> [expr.reinterpret.cast]/7:
> Any object pointer type T1* can be
> converted to another object pointer type cv T2*. This is exactly
> equivalent to static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(T1_var))
> (which implies that if T2's alignment requirement is not stricter than
> T1's, the value of the pointer does not change and conversion of the
> resulting pointer back to its original type yields the original value)

Am I wondering that there's no limitation while casting a pointer from one type to another using `reinterpret_cast`. The only thing I notice, when reading the given quote, is that the target type shall be stricter than the original type, [otherwise] not mentioned in this quote. For example

```
int *p = 0;
double *q = reinterpret_cast<double *>(p)
```

Here `alignof(int)` *is not greater (stricter?) than or equal* `alignof(double)`. Although the compiler gives no errors or even warnings, I think in this case, `q` pointer holds an unspecified value? and dereferencing it is undefined behavior.

So does this mean converting a pointer of type `T1*` into `T2*`, the resulting pointer always has an unspecified value as long as `static_assert(alignof(T1) >= alignof(T2))` fails?

Comment: Note that dereferencing the pointer after the cast is usually Undefined Behaviour (there are some exceptions for casting to types like `char*`).  All the Standard guarantees for casting pointers is that they can round-trip .

Comment: *dereferencing `q` is undefined behavior*  **Yes**, that is correct.  Regardless of alignment issues.

Comment: @Eljay, but `q` has unspecified value?

Comment: `q` has a specified value.  `*q` has an unspecified value (and **undefined behavior**), since `q` does not actually point to a `double`.  The alignment of `p` as a pointer value fulfills both `int` and `double` alignment requirements, because the pointer value is `0`.

Comment: @Eljay. Are you said `q` has specified value *because*  the type of the destination `double` has a less strict alignment requirement than the source `int`. or because what?

Comment: No.  I'm saying the result is only unspecified if the *actual* address pointed to by `p` **does not** fulfill the alignment requirements of the `q` type (`double*`).  And the address value of `0` does fulfill that requirement.

Comment: @Eljay So if `p` holds an address of `int` variable, now that address fulfills alignment requirements of the q type (double*)?

Comment: @Eljay _And the address value of `0` does fulfill that requirement._ Only pointers to objects or past the end _represent the address_. Null pointer values do not. So it is meaningless to say about the alignment requirement of the address represented by a null pointer value.

Comment: If `p` holds an address of `int` variable, and that address fulfills the alignment requirements of a `double`, then that address fulfills alignment requirements of the `q` type (`double*`).  And I'm sure that `0` (`nullptr`) fulfills the alignment requirement of every pointer.

Comment: @Eljay, "not stricter" means "greater". I am apologize, English is not my main language :(

Comment: @cpper Stricter alignment would mean larger number of bytes. I.e. address modulo larger number equals zero.

Comment: *"not stricter" means "greater"*  **No**, "not stricter" means "not greater".

Answer (score 1):

> *So does this mean converting a pointer of type T1* into T2*, the
> resulting pointer always has an unspecified value as long as
> static_assert(alignof(T1) >= alignof(T2)) fails?*

Not really. The result is only (but *always*) unspecified if the *actual* address of the `T1` type doesn't fulfil the alignment requirements of the `T2` type. It may do so, in which case the behaviour is well-defined.

The paragraph from the Standard you cite states the equivalence of a `reinterpret_cast` operation to two `static_cast` operations *via* an intermediate `void*` pointer. And, from the Standard, in the previous section about `static_cast` (bolding for emphasis mine):

> ##### 8.5.1.9 Static cast     [expr.static.cast]
>
> <sup>13</sup>     A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1*
> `void`” can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* T”,
> where T is an object type and *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as,
> or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*. If the original pointer value
> represents the address A of a byte in memory ***and A does not satisfy
> the alignment requirement of T, then the resulting pointer value is
> unspecified***. Otherwise, if the original pointer value points to an
> object a, and there is an object b of type T (ignoring
> cv-qualification) that is pointer-interconvertible (6.7.2) with a, the
> result is a pointer to b. Otherwise, the pointer value is unchanged by
> the conversion.

Comment: `*then the resulting pointer value is unspecified*`, they mean the value of the pointer itself or the value after dereferencing?

Comment: If the value of the pointer (i.e. the address it holds) is unspecified, then how can dereferencing it be anything better/other than unspecified?

Comment: ... but yes, the Standard quite clearly states that the **pointer value** is unspecified.

Comment: Thanks, but why editing I would have got it: "Not really. The result is only (but always) unspecified if the actual address of the T1 type doesn't fulfill the alignment requirements of the T2 type." That's why I said `static_assert(alignof(T1) >= alignof(T2))` if fail, then *T1 type doesn't fulfill the alignment requirements of the T2*, otherwise that's OK

Comment: My edit was to correct the post. The alignment requirement of a `char` is typically less than that of a `double`. However, one can declare a *specific* `char` variable that does have the alignment requirements for a `double`. (An example could be a `char` member of a struct that immediately follows a `double` member.)

Comment: @cpper You are conflating two different issues. Your assert works on alignment requirements of ***types*** but `reinterpret_cast` behaviour is determined by the addresses of ***actual variables***. In the case of the example in your quoted citation, the issue doesn't arise, because the type of the destination has a less strict alignment requirement than the source.

Comment: Can u tell me how I can check the alignment requirement of ***actual variables**; or post a new question?

Comment: Post a new question - that's not a trivial thing to do.

Comment: **"because the type of the destination has a less strict alignment requirement than the source"** How did you know that? actually this the exact point of my question

Comment: @cpper because that's what your quote says: *if T2's alignment requirement is not stricter than T1's*

Comment: @cpper • *How did you know that (the destination has a less strict alignment requirements than the source)?*  You could use `alignof`.